# What is the difference between transmission and transmission-daemon?

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, bittorrent, daemon, transmission

I have watched some tutorials on how to install torrent program on raspberry.

I have seen somebody installs like this:

```
sudo apt install transmission
```

Someone installs it like this:

```
sudo apt install transmission-daemon
```

Comment: Pretty sure transmission is the GUI version, and transmission-deamon is the CLI version.

Comment: @LPChip If i install the GUI version, I can still use command line also right?

Comment: I think so, yeah...

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the package descriptions using `apt show <name>`. They usually tell you exactly what the package consists of.

- The `transmission` package installs a regular client app (either the graphical GTK or Qt5 app, or the command-line one – no idea how 'apt' prioritizes them).

  - This is actually just an empty "metapackage" which only causes more packages to be installed through dependencies. In reality, each of the three versions has its own package: `transmission-gtk`, `-qt`, `-cli`.
- The `transmission-gtk` and `transmission-qt` packages install GUI apps meant to be used on a graphical desktop. (Though they do support remote access too.)
- The `transmission-daemon` package installs a *service* which always runs in background and is exclusively meant for remote access, either through the web UI or using a "remote" client.
- The `transmission-cli` package installs a command-line app which can only download one torrent at a time. (It is not a real terminal-based equivalent of transmission-gtk/qt, unfortunately.)

You can have *all* these packages installed at once, as long as you don't try to *run* the apps at the same time (GTK and Qt versions share all settings and torrents, so running them both at once would result in a mess).